# Does Apache Flume works only with Text data?

Tags: flume

Every tutorial about Apache Flume gives example of "logs getting continuously generated" as the example. 
I am curious if Flume works only on text data or it can also work with streaming data like audio, video, electronic sensor inputs ? 
Because irrespective of data type it is all bytes array.

Answer (score 0):

It is designed for text data streaming. It is possible to provide a schema definition for text data, so that the consumer of the data can process it after receiving it. Consumer of data can scale horizontally with the increasing size of data, still making use of commodity hardware(moderate cores/ RAM). However for binary data the reconstruction and parsing would be a heavily resource intensive operation.